# Facade Pattern for distributed application?

Tags: wcf

We are in the process defining the architecture of a fairly large customer facing financial application where performance and scalability are the key requirements. 
We proposed n-tier architecture which primary consists of Web Tier, Application Tier (Mid-Tier) and Data Tier WCF being the communication mechanism between web tier and app tier.   Some of the stakeholders are concerned that WCF would cause performance overhead and want configurable architectural provision to support In-process calls and WCF. Their vision is to start with in-process calls and change it to WCF based communication if horizontal scalability is a concern.

We are considering the following approaches:

- One architectural approach would be to introduce a client facade
  layer which can act as a facade between web and application layers.
  The façade layer would simply hide the complexity of the remote calls
  and allows for easy swapping of the façade for another one that might
  possibly implement a different remote call technology (ie. WCF)
- Another approach is to simply use WCF and use different bindings for
  different scenarios. For example, use IPC binding (Namedpipes) when
  web and application components are deployed in the same machine or
  use TCP binding when the application components are deployed in a
  different service (Both the ends use .NET so interoperability is not
  a concern )

We are looking for the right architectural approach for the above mentioned scenario.

Kindly advice.